# Is there a good Book Resource on modular web application architecture?

Tags: php, zend-framework, architecture

I am asking this question because of Zend Framework.  I really like it but still the way it offers modularity is not really flexible.  For instance a lot of us at first create default and admin module , but in reality it is not reusable.  In fact admin should be not a module but some paradigm that takes care of every single module's admin side (like a plug-in manager).

So, anyhow, *is* there are Good book on Architecture of Modular Web Application?

P.S. sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: The admin module could have a controller that is designed to manage other modules. Doing this would still maintain the 'modular' aspect you are looking for by allowing for you to remove both the 'admin' module and the other modules without affecting anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are several. But there is only one that is an absolute must read in the web framework world:

Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture:

- [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420)
- [Barnes & Noble](http://search.barnesandnoble.com/Patterns-of-Enterprise-Application-Architecture/Martin-Fowler/e/9780321127426/?itm=1&USRI=patterns+of+enterprise+application+architecture)

It is the de facto standard book with all patterns used through Zend Framework, and almost all other web frameworks. The Front Controller, the Router, the Service Layer, they all come from this book.

You can find a good summary on the web at [Fowler's site](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/)

Comment: I was contemplating naming PoEAA (and Domain Driven Design by Eric Evans) myself, but then felt it wouldn't really answer the question in regards to ZF's module architecture.

Comment: You are right, ZF's module architecture is very specific to ZF. There are of course a couple of books that deal with the ZF specifically. Akrabat's book comes to mind: http://www.amazon.com/Zend-Framework-Action-Rob-Allen/dp/1933988320

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Zend Framework 1.8 Zend Application Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194222).

There is a chapter about creating administration module, which is something you called 'some paradigm…'.